# Why can't I delete heapster and kubernetes-dashboard on gke namespace=kube-system

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to have full control of what I do with my single node cluster (savings...lol), but somehow I can't do this even if I delete the deployment it respawns ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heapster is configured as a cluster addon. The [addon manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager/README.md) is going to reconcile it to it's preconfigured state if you change or delete it.

You are stuck with it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in another answer, you cannot delete them directly via the Kubernetes API; however, you can delete them indirectly via the Google Container Engine API.

To remove the dashboard, run `gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER_NAME --update-addons=KubernetesDashboard=DISABLED`.

To disable heapster you need to disable monitoring using `gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER_NAME --monitoring-service=none` (it may actually require disabling another add-on too, I can't recall at the moment).

See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update for the commands referenced above.

Comment: tried the --update-addons got ```(gcloud.container.clusters.update) argument --update-addons: valid keys are [HorizontalPodAutoscaling, HttpLoadBalancing]; received: KubernetesDashboard```.. this ```gcloud container clusters update (name) --monitoring-service=none```also has no effect besides giving this response ```Updating scalable...done.                                                                                                                  
Updated [https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/(project-name)/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/(cluster-name)].```

Comment: Try `gcloud beta container clusters update ...` or `gcloud alpha container clusters update ...`. It may be that the documentation for the GA surface is incorrect (and a bit ahead of the implementation).

Comment: (bit ahead of the implementation) this maybe the reason. will wait a while until they fix ... nothing is working ... was only able to turn the L7 httpLoadbalancer so that works .. and thank you for your help

Comment: [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/small-cluster-tuning#configuring_add-ons)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you delete heapster pod; it restart automatically. I can made it with scaling it down to zero as shown below

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1 --namespace=kube-system
```

And you can find the exact name of the heapster pod within result of the command below

```
kubectl get deployments --namespace=kube-system
```

By the way you can find more options to reduce resource usage here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/small-cluster-tuning